# Paypal behavior when agreement payment fail

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions, paypal-rest-sdk

Searching for a while an answer to this basic question but I don't manage to find any answer.
I've created a web app in which user can subscribe monthly to get some features.
I've developed a bot which verifies daily if a user has paid and if it was successful.

So my questions are:

- If a payment fail on 01-jan-2016. Will PayPal retry on 02-jan-2016? Or will it retry on 01-feb-2016? Or will it never retry?
- In the object "agreement_details", there is a property "last_payment_date". If a payment failed. Is this property still updated? Or is "last_payment_date" updated only if payment is successful?
- What is the behavior of "outstanding_balance" property?

Thanks a lot in advance for your answers

Comment: Did you ever find the answers to your questions?

Comment: @Bex Not at all :(